# Anti copy authentication

Tags: android, ios, security, authentication, windows-phone

I'm doing my new cross-plateform mobile(iOS,Android,WP) game, and i want to secure it from copying and hacking, 
So, I would have to know what are the technics that developers use to do that.

waiting for your valuable comments and sugessions

Answer (score 0):

For do privileges of coping, you need to purchase TM (tread mark) so anybody can not take/use title of your mobile platform. and also do it copyRight so nobody can develop cross-plateform/project/games as  like yours. If anybody do it then you can blame of them.

And really i don't know about hacking so best way is ask to google god. :)

Answer (score 0):

To do that, there is principally two types of security:

1-Obfuscating the code.
2-Securing the access to the application (by mail/account authentication).

Answer (score 0):

This technique is all about how an application unpacks itself on the defined Operating system say Android just as an instance here.

The Operating system first sets a temporary repository, that allows the system to see the source code. You will not be able to block this from happening to your app, because if you don't let this happen, your app most likely will not run at all.
Someone with a will can always view your sourcecode if they get a copy of your apk (easily available on a rooted phone-androidor for an Apple Iphone Based App- A Jail~broken Phone).

The other side of the coin says that it is possibility to recreate the code snipps in a way that some pieces cannot be easily read by the Hacker.To do so there are several tools, I use [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) for instance it is a tool provided by Android that lets you obfuscate your code during packaging.

But please be aware this is also an application, so the communication engines are most likely to be decoded still, so keep them in a different package all together before binding. Remember Activity, Service, or BroadcastReceiver are the 3 things which are most likely to be searched by a hacker to work through.

To protect agains illegally copy and distribution of your application, you can use the source licensing offered by App Companies like for Android; Google Play offers services for licensing [Attached Documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html).

Anyways, At the end of the end, I have known that for every smart developer there is a more smart hacker present, just be cautions, create all config files with damn precaution, if using python bind all py scripts in a package and encrypt them. And Use a proper license key for the final package.

REMEMBER TO OBFUSCATE YOUR CODE.

Comment: if you want a more specific answer please share some code to help you better